# Play sound after any use of the 'make' command

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

Since my laptop is not the newest and I like power naps, I want to play a sound after compiling something with `make` on linux. Basically, I want to replace any kind of command

```
make <XYZ>
```

with something like

```
make <XYZ>  && paplay done.ogg
```

Bonus would be to have different sounds for successfully compiling or compiling with errors.
I want to be sure not to mess up any uses of `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `.bash_profile` or similar.

```
function make () {
    command make "$@" && paplay $HOME/boink/success.ogg || paplay $HOME/boink/failure.ogg
}
```

The trick here is to name the function like the command, and refer to the original command with `command`.  Thus you have your own wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Qt creator uses `/usr/bin/make` directly, can I also redirect that or shouldn't I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't replace system binaries lightly, no. Perhaps there is a way to reconfigure Qr creator instead?

Comment: Wouldn't replacing it break this solution anyway?

Comment: Indeed in would, but you could refactor this to be a system binary `/usr/local/bin/make` and have it call the real `/usr/bin/make` instead of `command make`.